# Why does not my Android app work with some android versions?

Tags: java, android, apk

I created my application. It works fine on my device, but I noticed that it does not work with some android versions (Android 7.1.1) My library supports android 4.2 and above. The device I tested is android 6.0. What could be the reason for this. How do I set it up for android 4.2?

My Grandle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    applicationId "test"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    resConfigs "en"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
   "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
  'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.+'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.+'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'

implementation 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.7'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

implementation "com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.7.9"

implementation 'com.baoyz.pullrefreshlayout:library:1.2.0'

implementation 'com.github.Hitomis:CircleMenu:v1.1.0'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: post your log as wel

Comment: Please clarify "does not work"

Comment: You need to post the error log or the issue you are having in 7.1.1, Suggestion for you though, avoid using + in version numbers as this can lead to unpredictable and unrepeatable builds. (you should be getting this as a warning in Android Studio as well)

Comment: Possibly having issues from vector drawables.

Comment: hehe :-) Point shoot, bravo. @MbuodileObiosio The problem is vector drawing. I thank you all for responding. I'm sorry to forget to add a log cat.